# Ember.js: How do I bind a handler that should be called when records are loaded into DS.RecordArray?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Using Ember.js, with Ember Data, when doing `Model.find()` I'd like to be able to bind a handler that gets called as soon as records are available in the resulting `DS.RecordArray`. I've found a solution, but I feel there must be a better way.

My current solution uses [Array.addArrayObserver](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_addArrayObserver), e.g. for some imaginary model, `App.Widget`:

```js
// Find the widgets!
var widgets = App.Widget.find();

// Get notified when widget records are available...
var arrayObserver = Ember.Object.create({
    arrayWillChange: function(start, removeCount, addCount) {
        // Widget records are about to be loaded.
    },
    arrayDidChange: function(start, removeCount, addCount) {
        // Widget records have now been loaded.
        var myWidget = widgets.objectAt(0);
    }
});

// Add the above arrayObserver to the widgets array
widgets.addArrayObserver(arrayObserver);
```

Is this the established method of achieving what I want, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Promises](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/) to achieve this...

```js
// Find the widgets!
App.Widget.find()
    .then(function(widgets) {
        var myWidget = widgets.objectAt(0);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In a controller that binds to the required data, you can observe the content.isLoaded property, which will be set to true once the store adapter has loaded the data:

```
contentLoaded: function() {
    console.log('controller content is loaded from store');
}.observes('content.isLoaded')
```

Comment: Thanks, in this case though I am loading records in the redirect method of my `Index` route. I'm surprised there is a `widgets.on("loaded", function(){...` shortcut, or something similar.